# Set the text of a Bukkit config file by default (PaperMc 1.15)

Tags: java, bukkit

I created a Locale setting so Italian, English, ... I needed to know how to set up a predefined config already: I have obviously tried how every good person does this but I think it is too inefficient, I also tried to create files through the IDE in the same location where the files in the DataFolder are created at the onEnable but obviously it didn't work, however what I tried to be ineffective is this: `customConfig.set("Hi-Message", "I'm sorry, i love you");`

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm doing it right now, is simply having the config file in the source code itself and, if the file-version of the config does not exist yet, creates a new config file using the config file from the compiled source code.

In my `onEnable` method in `Main`, I simply call a method in another class `FileManager.setup()`.

It looks a bit like this in setup():

```
    public static void setup() throws IOException {
        
        File plugin_work_directory = new File(plugin_work_path);
        
        core_server_config = new File(plugin_work_path + "config.txt");

        if (!plugin_work_directory.exists()) plugin_work_directory.mkdir();

        if (!core_server_config.exists()) {
            
            InputStream core_server_config_template = (Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.txt"));
            Files.copy(core_server_config_template, Paths.get(plugin_work_path + "config.txt"));
        }

        Config.load();

        if (Integer.parseInt(Config.getValue("config.version")) < Config.version) {
            
            core_server_config.delete();
            InputStream core_server_config_template = (Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.txt"));
            Files.copy(core_server_config_template, Paths.get(plugin_work_path + "config.txt"));
        }

        Config.load();
    }
```

`Config.load()` parses the values into a private hashmap of the Config class, whereby other classes can reference the hashmap through a `String getValue(String string)` method.